# At which temperature does carbon monoxide explode?

Tags: temperature

I had doubt whether carbon monoxide explodes or not. I checked out this [resource](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/carbon_monoxide#section=Safety-and-Hazards) and found out that carbon monoxide explodes when heated. But they didn't mention the temperature at which it explodes. So my question is that at which temperature does carbon monoxide **explode** and also at which **pressure**?

Comment: The key explosive risk is from flammability with oxygen in air, described in your linked table as "explosive limits, vol% in air: 12.5%-74.2%".  More chemistry than physics.

Answer (score 4):

> **At which temperature does carbon monoxide explode?**

At a wide range of temperatures.

If mixed with air in a proportion between 12 and 75% it is explosive (assuming a there is an ignition source) - I think this is at standard temperature and pressure - 273K, 0.1 MPa.

Note that 1% of CO in air will cause death within 3 minutes due to its toxic effects.

Comment: Does that mean that if there is no ignition source and we supply lots of heat it will not explode?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean autoignition. Carbon monoxide autoignites at $609~\mathrm{^\circ C}$, as stated in [this website](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/fuels-ignition-temperatures-d_171.html).

Comment: Well, this is a perfectly fine answer. The question is only asking for the number and you provided it, so don't feel bad about posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

On it's own Carbon Monoxide will not explode no matter how much you heat it, unless it is mixed with an Oxidizer. Which is more than can be said for a lot of other gases such as Acetylene.